# Inserting Canvas into an img tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I'd like insert the canvas data into an img tag. That's possible?

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200px" height="200px" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"> Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<img id="insertHereTheCanvas" src="" alt="" width="200px" height="200px" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></img>
```

If I use `canvas.toDataURL("image/png");` I can see a value how this: `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw...`

But I'd like to fill the img tag content and load the same image than the canvas. Here is my code so far:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    var c=$("#myCanvas")[0];
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var img = new Image(200,200);
    img.src = "http://www.nimbosfera.com/uploads/empresas/empresa-235.jpg?20140920";
    img.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
        ctx.textAlign="center";
        ctx.font = "12pt Courie bold";
        ctx.fillText("MI TEXTO", 100, 150);
    }


  var dataURL = c.toDataURL("image/png");
  alert(dataURL); // data:image/png;base64,iVBORw...

})
```

[Here the question on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oscarvady/oqn3zqyL/)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Make sure image is loaded from same origin (typically domain) or you need to set `crossOrigin` to anonymous (see fiddle) or you'll get an security error when extracting the image to data-uri (please note: this may or may not be the case for your final page, but from the fiddle this is evident - I copied the image to a host which supports cross-origin use).
- You can set image source directly with the data-uri `toDataURL()` returns.
- Make sure to extract the data-uri AFTER image has loaded properly and been drawn, ie. inside the `onload` handler, or you'll risk ending up with an empty canvas and string. You probably want to call your next step in the code from here as well.

**[Modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oqn3zqyL/1/)**